# How does Pact of the Blade handle magic paired weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock

Pact of the Blade gives you a melee weapon of your choice or allows you to bond one you already have, except Artifact weapons.

But if the weapon is a paired set, does the bond affect both?

For example, if I made up "Twin Fangs", a pair of magic +1 daggers; do you bond both or only bond with one and are forced to carry the other one? What if the paired weapon can't function or loses function without the other?

Comment: I clarified your question based on my understanding.

Comment: Because this is a homebrewed weapon, you may wish to specify that you'd like suggestions or recommendations on how to make this house rule balanced, or how to apply different game mechanics to it. However, this site does not take kindly to topics that provoke broad discussions, or allow mostly opinionated answers. If you can find a way to reword your question in order to produce a specific, based on mechanics or rules answer, then that would be your best bet, but try to avoid questions that are unclear or too broad.

Answer (score 18):

## Paired Weapons don't exist in D&D 5e

Other systems may have this concept, but not this system. If you were to introduce them into your game, then that is homebrew, to which the vanilla system would not have any rules for. So, if introduced into the game, there is no answer the core rulebooks can give you.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver You've asked for how the rules function and received an appropriate answer. Providing homebrew isn't necessary to answer the question here and it's poor etiquette to expect people to provide additional work outside the scope of the question. More importantly though, we only accept "homebrew this thing for me" requests [if they pass certain quality criteria to make suggestions non-arbitrary](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5325/1204) -- I suggest you study those criteria and ask a new question requesting assistance in creating homebrew to achieve a specific outcome.

Answer (score 3):

As markovchain stated, paired weapons do not exist in D&D5e. Seeing as you are homebrewing the weapons to begin with, it seems best that you homebrew a house rule on the matter as well. If you are going to add something to the game, always think about how it would affect it, and what accommodations you may have to make to implement the addition. The best thing for you to do in this instance would be to speak with your DM and work out a whether or not this addition seems fair or balanced, and then working out a means of how it will work. It may also be good to note the opinions of all of the players in the session, as this specific rule is a bit overpowered, which is why a rule like this does not exist in the first place. When it comes to homebrewing, do what you think will enhance the experience of everyone at the table, not just yourself or your character.

By the logic of this homebrewed "Pair of Weapons", mechanically, you may rule that his is one weapon with duel wielding properties, if that will help you with other mechanics of your game.

There are plenty of sites and the like on the internet [like this one](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_Homebrew) that may further assist you with configuring your house rules and homebrews to work with the game and your specific campaign.

Answer (score 2):

*How does Pact of the Blade handle magic paired weapons?*

Pact of the Blade PHB p.108

> You can transform *one* magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon.

A pair of weapons is two weapons however you count them. So only one of a pair could possibly become the pact weapon.

If they don't work unless together, when one is in the extra-dimensional space then the other one would therefore not work. If their magic means they cannot be separated then dismissing the pact weapon would fail or possibly break the magic depending on the DM's judgement and the details of the magic items.

Comment: Please [do answer the question directly as well](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently). That comment specifically *should not* be taken as an invitation to pass up answering the core question. Please also be aware that [homebrew is only an acceptable answer when it can be backed up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/); we're not interested in handling opinion or armchair answers -- which is precisely why I responded to the querent the way I did. (I am removing that "suggestions" comment.)

Comment: Exactly how does this  not address the core question? "How does Pact of the Blade handle magic paired weapons?" It states exactly how it would handle them.

Comment: I have changed the single top line as you have removed the comment, and nothing else, and it still answers the question.

Comment: It is not homebrew - it answers using RAW and the concept of a DM created item that is somehow paired. It does not enter into what "pairing" means and references the fact that that is down to the DM.

Comment: Ok, I reversed my vote. Your first sentence originally had me primed to read the post differently; it looks reasonable now that I give it a re-read.